# web.xml formatting in SO questions shows grayed out or commented out code though its not commented out

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, code-formatting

[image]

Refer this image in which  had a /messagebroker/* as required and formatting misunderstood it as commented out code.
Please correct me if I am missing anything.

Comment: @nhahtdh sorry, but I didn't know about this. :( I tried rene's method and it worked like charm. :) Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code that is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293797/tomcat-startup-web-xml-issue) uses the language hint of the [java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) (scroll to the end of the wiki page). In java `/*` denotes the start of a multi-line comment. The prettifier works.

To get the correct syntax highlighting for the XML block override the default by adding an inline language hint by adding `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` before the code block. make sure to have an extra empty line before and after the language hint. The result will be like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>filedownload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>demo3.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>crystal_image_use_relative</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>webapp</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

All is fine now. With the `lang-java` hint it looks like:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>filedownload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>demo3.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>crystal_image_use_relative</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>webapp</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

which is all wrong.

Comment: thankyou @rene for answer. I didn't know about this formatting. :) Marking it as answer.